# Given a Uri and a UriTemplate, how to get template parameter values?

Tags: c#, uri

If I have access to both a Uri and the UriTemplate on which is is based, what is the neatest way to discover the values that have replaced the parameters in the template?

For example, if I know:

```
        var uriTemplate = new UriTemplate("/product-catalogue/categories/{categoryName}/products/{product-name}");
        var uri = new Uri("/product-catalogue/categories/foo/products/bar");
```

is there a built-in way for me to discover that categoryName = "foo" and productName = "bar"?

I was hoping to find a method like:

```
        var parameterValues = uriTemplate.GetParameterValues(uri);
```

where parameterValues would be:

```
         { { "categoryName", "foo" }, { "productName", "bar" }}
```

Clearly, I could write my own, but I was wondering if there was something in framework I could use.

Thanks

Sandy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the [Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uritemplate.match.aspx) method on the `uriTemplate` instance and use the returned [UriTemplateMatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uritemplatematch.aspx) instance to access the parameter values:

```
var uriTemplate = new UriTemplate("/product-catalogue/categories/{categoryName}/products/{product-name}"); 
var uri = new Uri("http://www.localhost/product-catalogue/categories/foo/products/bar"); 
var baseUri = new Uri("http://www.localhost");

var match = uriTemplate.Match(baseUri, uri);

foreach (string variableName in match.BoundVariables.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", variableName, match.BoundVariables[variableName]);
}
```

outputs

```
CATEGORYNAME: foo
PRODUCT-NAME: bar
```

Comment: Note that there appears to be a bug, where your template parameters are capitalised in the NameValueCollection returned by Match, so therefore, the string names (of the keys) in the UriTemplate and the match collection don't match.