# Given a Uri and a UriTemplate, how to get template parameter values In java

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

Below solution is provided in C#. I want to know if similar solution exist in Java with jersey classes.

[Given a Uri and a UriTemplate, how to get template parameter values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546043/given-a-uri-and-a-uritemplate-how-to-get-template-parameter-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's even called UriTemplate:

https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.17/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/uri/UriTemplate.html

```
UriTemplate uriTemplate = new UriTemplate("/product-catalogue/categories/{categoryName}/products/{product-name}");
```

And it even has the same `.match()` method:

```
String uri = "/product-catalogue/categories/foo/products/bar";
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();

uriTemplate.match(uri, parameters);
```